# Java is not printing in a different class that doesn't contain main

Tags: java

I've been experimenting with OOP with this code. I just started taking Stanford's CS106A, and since it uses the ACM library, the syntax might be a little off.

So, here is the javadoc, http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/ConsoleProgram.html

I'm using two classes named "itunes" and "test". "test" is the class that contains the "main", but here it uses the "run" method which is kind of analogous to the "main" method.

first class, "test"

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;

public class test extends ConsoleProgram{
    public void run(){

        itunes song1=new itunes("acdc",1991);
        song1.displaySong();

    }
}
```

Second class, "itunes"

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;

public class itunes extends ConsoleProgram {
    private static String name;
    private static int year;

    public itunes(String name1,int year1){
        name = name1;
        year = year1;
    }

    public void displaySong(){
        println(name);
        println(year);

    }
}
```

It compiles without errors but nothing appears on the console. Blank.
But if I return those values to run and then display them within run, it works.Any idea why this is happening?

Also if I wanted to return both the string name and int year from a single function, can I do that? In that case what will be the return type?

Comment: Please show us the code that calls `run()` and where `println()` is defined.

Comment: regarding returning the string and int: you could create a data type that contains a String and an int. Then set each, then return that object.

Comment: Concerning the second part of the question, you have direct acces to the string and the int from the song1 instance: song1.name and song1.year

Comment: Why does your `itunes` class extend ConsoleProgram?  I don't know how the ACM library works, but it seems likely to me that you are only supposed to have one ConsoleProgram in your program.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I extended the ConsoleProgram to the itunes class so that, I could use println in one of it's methods. Is there any other way I could use println within itunes class?

Comment: On an unrelated note, use Java naming conventions: Class names start with a capital letter. This will make your code easier to read (and if you edit your question, you'll even see improved syntax highlighting).

Comment: @Riadh I don't have direct access to name and year as they're private to class itunes. So I can access them only through public member functions of class itunes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your itunes Class is extending `ConsoleProgram` as well.

That means, the moment you create an instance of this class, a *second* console will be created, where the output of that class goes to.

For this reason, you are seeing the output if you `return` the values (they are printed by the first `ConsoleProgram`, working with the first Console you are currently viewing.)

You should either switch your console view (assuming eclipse) or don't create a second `ConsoleProgram` from within your main program. It seems like a regular class (without extending `ConsoleProgram`) would serve your needs.

---

> Also if I wanted to return both the string name and int year from a
>   single function, 
>       can I do that? In that case what will be the return type?

There are various options:

- You could return a `List<Object>` with a specific position for each returned value.
- You could use private properties (and getters) in the `iTunes` class, ans access your result after processing the input (`itunes.getName(); itunes.getYear();`)
- You could create your own Result Object, containing all the required return parameters.
- and many more ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using eclipse. How do I switch my console view?

Comment: @user10678 http://www.codeaffine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/select-console-dropdown.png - Click on the Icon that looks like a computer screen with text on it. You could also configure eclipse to switch to the console with the latest output automatically.

Comment: @user10678 please also see the comment on Titus Answer... The IOConsole is kind of special - but I think eclipse should handle it as well...

Comment: Thanks for the image. I tried switching consoles, but didn't get any output.

Answer (score 1):

The `println()` method of the `ConsoleProgram` class doesn't print the object to the standard output, it prints it to the `IOConsole` which is an `java.awt.Container` that has to be added to a `Frame` of `JFrame`. If you want to print those values to the console use `System.out.println(...)` instead.

In answer to your second question. To return both an `int` and a `String` you can set that method's return type to `Object[]` but in this case you should create some Getters and Setters for the `itunes` class.

Comment: True, the `println()` works kind of different, see http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/46 - not sure if it is STILL possible to switch console views from within eclipse.

Comment: You are right. I tried system.out.println in the itunes class and it worked. I'm curious as to how you figured it out. Wanted to know how I could go about, the next time I troubleshoot.

Comment: @user10678 I've read the documentation. The relevant information is displayed in the [IOConsole](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/io/IOConsole.html) class description.